# How do I keep my login session between my cucumber steps?

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

I am trying to test a scenario where my user logs in, and then navigates to another page on the site but my login state is lost after the login state step.

My Gherkin looks something like this:

```
Scenario: Verify this random link
    Given I am logged in
    When I go to this page
    Then I can see this link
```

And the code:

```
public class Checkout {
    WebDriver driver;
    driver = DriverFactory.open("Chrome"); 
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    String URL = "https://www.example.com/";

@Given("^I am logged in$")
public void i_am_logged_in() {
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("test");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("123");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/some/xpath")).click();
}

@When("^I go to this page$")
public void i_go_to_this_page(){
    driver.get(URL + "instance1");
}
```

The code runs fine for the login in the first step, but in the next step I can see that I'm logged out.

Could I get some help please?

SOLVED!

All I had to do was to add an assertion to my login step to verify that I am logged in at all (Thanks Kyle!)

Here is the code I added to the login step:

```
String logoutButton = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).getText();
Assert.assertTrue(logoutButton.contains("Logout"));
```

Comment: If you're closing the browser, or removing all cookies after each scenario, that would be the problem. But you'll want to change your login step slightly too, to make sure that you're logged in as the right person before you continue (or that you're logged in at all) in order to make sure that all of your scenarios can be run on their own (without the need of already being logged in to run)

Comment: @KyleFairns Asserting that I am logged in the login step did the trick. Thanks a lot!


Here's the code I added to the login step:
```String logoutButton = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).getText();
        Assert.assertTrue(logoutButton.contains("Logout"));```